# Check for empty TextField from PickerView - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, pickerview

I have two TextFields that I want to check if they are empty. One is getting the Data by Keyboard input and the other gets the Data from a PickerView.

I used this before I changed the second TextField from Keyboard input to PickerView input:

```
func setupAddTargetIsNotEmptyTextFields() {
    saveCupboardButton.isHidden = true //hidden okButton
    saveViewButtonBorder.isHidden = true
    addCupboardTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldsIsNotEmpty),
                                for: .editingChanged)
    addCupboardTypeTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldsIsNotEmpty),
                                 for: .editingChanged)

}

@objc func textFieldsIsNotEmpty(sender: UITextField) {
    sender.text = sender.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)

    guard
        let name = addCupboardTextField.text, !name.isEmpty,
        let type = addCupboardTypeTextField.text, !type.isEmpty
        else
    {
        self.saveCupboardButton.isHidden = true
        self.saveViewButtonBorder.isHidden = true
        return
    }
    // enable okButton if all conditions are met
    saveCupboardButton.isHidden = false
    saveViewButtonBorder.isHidden = false
}
```

This worked great but then I added the PickerView:

```
func createPicker() {

    //        toolbar
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()

    //        doneButton
    let done = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressed))
    toolbar.setItems([done], animated: false)

    addCupboardTypeTextField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    addCupboardTypeTextField.inputView = picker
}


@objc func donePressed() {
    addCupboardTypeTextField.text = pick
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Cause of my `addTarget .editing changed` it won't check if there is something changed when the PickerView sets the data. Is there a way to fix that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: when you set the text programmatically the editing state does not change, make since? so it's already not editing and end editing does not trigger anything

Comment: Is there an other state that workes?

Comment: call `textFieldsIsNotEmpty` instead of `endEditing`

Comment: by the way you're changing the editing state on the view not on addCupboardTypeTextField

Comment: `endEditing` closes the PIckerView.